# Does Call of Duty on the Xbox One use more data online?

Tags: version-differences, call-of-duty-ghosts, call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

Do the Xbox One versions of *Call of Duty Ghosts* and *Advanced Warfare* use more data playing online then they did/do on the Xbox 360?

Comment: although I can't say if the games themselves use more data. the system itself [does](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162234/does-xbox-one-need-more-internet-than-360). You can always check how much bandwidth you are using in the system's network settings screen.

Comment: I doubt it. Why would it use more data?

Answer (score -3):

Generally it does, because of the more intensive load of the graphics and features.